# How to build a list of a certain item on a list of tuples. PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to make a list of the third items of tuples in a list as:

```
[(1, 1, '3D'), (2, 2, '4H'), (2, 3, '4S'), (5, 2, '7H'), (7, 2, '9H'), (8, 2, '10H'), (9, 0, 'JC'), (10, 1, 'QD'), (10, 2, 'QH'), (10, 3, 'QS')]
```

I would like to get:

```
['3D', '4H', '4S', '7H', '9H', '10H', 'JC', 'QD', 'QH', 'QS']
```

Comment: `map(lambda x:x[-1], data)` map can be used.

Answer (score 4):

You could use list_comprehension.

```
>>> l =[(1, 1, '3D'), (2, 2, '4H'), (2, 3, '4S'), (5, 2, '7H'), (7, 2, '9H'), (8, 2, '10H'), (9, 0, 'JC'), (10, 1, 'QD'), (10, 2, 'QH'), (10, 3, 'QS')]
>>> [z for x,y,z in l]
['3D', '4H', '4S', '7H', '9H', '10H', 'JC', 'QD', 'QH', 'QS']
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want

```
[subtuple[-1] for subtuple in thelist]
```

i.e, the list of the **last** items in each subtuple (item) of the list.

Answer (score 4):

```
x=[(1, 1, '3D'), (2, 2, '4H'), (2, 3, '4S'), (5, 2, '7H'), (7, 2, '9H'), (8, 2, '10H'), (9, 0, 'JC'), (10, 1, 'QD'), (10, 2, 'QH'), (10, 3, 'QS')]

[i[2] for i in x]
```

Output:`['3D', '4H', '4S', '7H', '9H', '10H', 'JC', 'QD', 'QH', 'QS']`

You can do this simply this way.